# Windows Phone 8.0 To Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, dispatcher

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 (WINRT) App**. I have a code given by *@Sergio0694* which is running good on Windows Phone 8.0 /Silverlight. It **compresses user photo picked from gallery and then converts to base64  string.**

Its not working on Windows Phone 8.1. Can anyone help me ?

```
public static async Task<String> ToCompressedBase64(this StorageFile imageFile, Page localPage)
{
    //Get the stream from the StorageFile
    IRandomAccessStream imageStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Original size ---> " + imageStream.ToFileSize());

    //Compresses the image if it exceedes the maximum file size
    imageStream.Seek(0);
    BitmapDecoder compressDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
    PixelDataProvider compressionData = await compressDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
    byte[] compressionBytes = compressionData.DetachPixelData();

    //Set target compression quality
    BitmapPropertySet propertySet = new BitmapPropertySet();
    BitmapTypedValue qualityValue = new BitmapTypedValue(0.5, PropertyType.Single);
    propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue);

    imageStream.Seek(0);
    imageStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    BitmapEncoder compressionEncoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, imageStream, propertySet);
    compressionEncoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                                    compressDecoder.PixelWidth, compressDecoder.PixelHeight,
                                    compressDecoder.DpiX, compressDecoder.DpiY, compressionBytes);
    await compressionEncoder.FlushAsync();

    //Create a BitmapDecoder from the stream
    BitmapDecoder resizeDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
#if DEBUG
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Old height and width ---> " + resizeDecoder.PixelHeight + " * " + resizeDecoder.PixelWidth + "\nCompressed size ---> " + imageStream.ToFileSize());
#endif
    //Resize the image if needed
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    localPage.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        const int maxImageWidth = 48;
        if (resizeDecoder.PixelWidth > maxImageWidth)
        {
            //Resize the image if it exceedes the maximum width
            int newHeight = (int)(maxImageWidth * resizeDecoder.PixelHeight / resizeDecoder.PixelWidth);
            WriteableBitmap tempBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)resizeDecoder.PixelWidth, (int)resizeDecoder.PixelHeight);
            imageStream.Seek(0);
            await tempBitmap.SetSourceAsync(imageStream);
            WriteableBitmap resizedImage = tempBitmap.Resize(maxImageWidth, newHeight, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);

            //Assign to imageStream the resized WriteableBitmap
            InMemoryRandomAccessStream resizedStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            await resizedImage.ToStream(resizedStream, BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId);
            imageStream = resizedStream;
        }
        completionSource.SetResult(true);
    }).Forget();
    await completionSource.Task;           

    //Converts the final image into a Base64 String
    imageStream.Seek(0);

    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
    PixelDataProvider pixels = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
#if DEBUG
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("New height and width ---> " + decoder.PixelHeight + " * " + decoder.PixelWidth + "\nSize after resize ---> " + imageStream.ToFileSize());
#endif
    byte[] bytes = pixels.DetachPixelData();

    //Encode image
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream encoded = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, encoded);
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, decoder.PixelWidth, decoder.PixelHeight, decoder.DpiX, decoder.DpiY, bytes);
    await encoder.FlushAsync();
    encoded.Seek(0);

    //Read bytes
    byte[] outBytes = new byte[encoded.Size];
    await encoded.AsStream().ReadAsync(outBytes, 0, outBytes.Length);

    //Create Base64
    return Convert.ToBase64String(outBytes);
}
```

Comment: By "not working" you mean it crashes, or does nothing or you can't even build/compile the app?

Comment: actually some of the methods above are not working in windows phone 8.1 like .Forget(); .. so i tried to modify it, but it hangs while converting big images

Answer (score 0):

When using `TaskCompletionSource` and awaiting on it, in addition to setting the result with `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult` you should also handle any exception that may occur that will not be bubbled up when you await on `TaskCompletionSource.Task` by calling `TaskCompletionSource.SetException`.

It's very likely that when you were dealing with a big file an exception was being thrown and thus your `await completionSource.Task` would then hang due to `SetResult` not being called.

To illustrate this here's an example of code that does what you're trying to do with the dispatcher w/o your logic but also handles the exception as explained above:

```
public async Task<string> TestTaskCompletionSource(CoreDispatcher dispatcher)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Before delay");
            await Task.Delay(100);
            Debug.WriteLine("After delay and before exception");
            throw new Exception("Test");
#pragma warning disable 162
            completionSource.SetResult(true);
#pragma warning restore 162
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            completionSource.SetException(e);
        }
    });
    await completionSource.Task;

    return "Test";
}
```